# Limitation on Subscription contract error log

Tags: installation, integration, peoplesoft

I've encountered an issue while monitoring some failed message in my integration broker. When I look at details and click on error messages I've got only 50 lines ... So I'm not able to check what's really going on in there during process.
(*PeopleTools* -> *Integration Broker* -> *Service Operations Monitor* -> *Monitoring* -> *Asynchronous Details*)

I've tried to retrieve the log directly form **PSIBERRP** , but as you could expect , there's also only 50 lines for one transaction ID in it.

I'm on **Tools 8.50.06**, I checked in books and some request on google, asked around me , and no one have any idea about how unlock this limit.

Does anyone know about some settings to remove this limit ?